# Proton Gen2 - Engine Oil

Tags: engine, maintenance, proton, gen2

what brand or oil type should I use for Proton gen2 (2004)?
and is it a good idea to flush the engine oil, it has 135K mileage so far.

I don't have the owner's manual.

Comment: I've added the tags for you

Comment: What does it say in the workshop or owners manual? If not, ask at the dealer - they will tell you the grade and amount.

Comment: See this page....http://www.whichoil.info/

Comment: @SolarMike yeah, that's the problem, I don't have the Owner's Manual and the company don't have it too, asking me to go to their service center, which doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: @Moab awesome, they have my car model, I can use `Helix HX7 10W-40 Premium oil` or `Helix HX5 10W-40 (SN)`, Thanks